# Since installing mathematica 9 I can't import certain tiffs

Tags: import

I have a notebook written in Mathematica 8 in which I imported Tiff images and everything worked fine. Since I installed Mathematica 9, I get the error:

```
In[14]:= Files[[1]][[1]]
Import[Files[[1]][[1]],"TIFF"]
Out[14]= Growth_1_130124_1353/Growth_1_130124_1353_T0001.tif
During evaluation of In[14]:= Image::imgcsmis: The specified color space ColorProfileData[<>,Description->sRGB IEC61966-2.1,DeviceColorSpace->RGB,IndependentColorSpace->XYZ] and the number of channels 1 are not compatible. >>
Out[15]= Image[RawArray[Byte,<1024,1360>],Byte,ColorSpace->ColorProfileData[<>,Description->sRGB IEC61966-2.1,DeviceColorSpace->RGB,IndependentColorSpace->XYZ],Interleaving->None]
```

How can I solve it?
Cheers,
Andrea

Comment: I found example TIFF images from old _Mathematica_ versions; can you import [this](http://imgur.com/Zjfx8m6) ?

Comment: Perhaps you could upload the TIFF file that's problematic? I've seen no problems with TIFF files on my system.

Comment: Sure, this is the TIFF that doesn't import in my notebook https://dl.dropbox.com/u/7754460/Growth_1_130124_1353_T0001.tif

Comment: I can confirm it works in 8.0.4 but not in 9. The image is ok with other software.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! I'd also suggest you pick a more interesting user name.

Answer (score 4):

Photoshop complains that the ICC color profile of this picture is invalid and is ignoring it. So, there might be a problem with the picture itself. It is a 1-channel grayscale image but it reports a 3-channel RGB color space.

Mathematica 9 has the new `ColorProfileData` object which represents this information, and the importer wants to make use of that. Since the information contained in the file header apparently is incorrect Mathematica 9 has a problem here, where previous versions worked.

There is a workaround though, simply overwriting this incorrect information:

```
res = Import["https://dl.dropbox.com/u/7754460/Growth_1_130124_1353_T0001.tif"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
res[[3]] = ColorSpace -> "Gray";

res
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it might be a problem introduced with the colorprofile additions. Perhaps Mathematica's getting confused with the grayscale model and RGB profile? Opens fine in Preview.

[image: image details]

Comment: Thank you very much for the workaround, I'll go for it for the moment. Thanks!